A film about a evil guy who create a chaos in village
I can only remember a few scenes from this film but I hope someone can help me.
At the start of film it shows that an old guy is going to a village with some kind of decoration in front of his rear view mirror. When he gets there he influences people of the village and create chaos in the village. 
For example by tempting villagers to fight with each other, lose their moneys by betting, burning houses or something like that. 
At the of the movie it shows that after he messed the entire village he is leaving the village in his car.
I think it produced before 2005. 
I think it is an American movie.

It might be Needful Things(1993)
From Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needful_Things_(film):

A mysterious proprietor named Leland Gaunt (Max von Sydow), claiming
  to be from Akron, Ohio, arrives in the small town of Castle Rock,
  Maine in a sinister-looking black car and opens a new antique store
  called "Needful Things"
...
then departs,
  presumably to continue his vicious evil work elsewhere, leaving in the
  same black car in which he arrived.

